# List all folders and subfolders in cmd, but not the files

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd, directory

New to using cmd, just wanted to know is there a way to list all folders their subfolders, if any, but not the files.

e.g.`D:\Movies\ dir /s /b` gives me list of all files and folders located in `Movies`, and also its subfolders e.g. `D:\Movies\Watched`.

I would like to display only folders its subfolders, not their files. Is it possible?

Comment: an alternative (maybe useless for you): `tree`

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Yes, this is possible as it can be read on running in a command prompt window `dir /?` which outputs the help for command **DIR**.

```
dir D:\Movies\* /AD /B /ON /S
```

This command outputs

- only directories because of `/AD` (attribute directory) including those with hidden attribute set,
- with only the names of the directories because of `/B` (bare format),
- with all subdirectories in a directory sorted by name because of `/ON` (order by name)
- of specified directory `D:\Movies` and all subdirectories because of `/S` and
- with full path of each directory also because of `/S`.

A small modification of the command line is needed to ignore directories with hidden attribute set:

```
dir D:\Movies\* /AD-H /B /ON /S
```

`-H` after `/AD` results in ignoring hidden directories.

See also:

- [Microsoft's command-line reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/windows-commands)
- [SS64.com - A-Z index of the Windows CMD command line](https://ss64.com/nt/)

Comment: I prefer to end with the variable-length sequence of directories to be listed, e.g. `dir /ad-h-s /b /on /s d:\videos d:\pictures d:\music [...]`.